# How do I remove ?action= using url rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My site uses strings such as:

http://www.website.com/?action=blue_widgets

I'd like to rewrite this to display:

http://www.website.com/blue_widgets

Firstly, is this advisable? Secondly how should I achieve this?

Comment: Please revisit your question and edit the rewritten URL. They're both the same righ tnow.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Add this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /?action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```